# Show only list of tables without child partitions

Tags: postgresql, psql, partitioning

I would like to show only the list of top level tables without child partitioned tables in PostgreSQL. (Currently using PostgreSQL 12.)

`\dt` in psql gives me all tables, including partitions of tables. I see this:

```
postgres=# \dt

                         List of relations

 Schema |             Name             |       Type        | Owner  
--------+------------------------------+-------------------+--------  
public  | tablea                       | table             | me
public  | partitionedtable1            | partitioned table | me
public  | partitionedtable1_part1      | table             | me
public  | partitionedtable1_part2      | table             | me
public  | partitionedtable1_part3      | table             | me
public  | tableb                       | table             | me
```

But I want a list like this, without child partitions of the parent partitioned table:

```
                         List of relations

 Schema |             Name             |       Type        | Owner  
--------+------------------------------+-------------------+--------  
public  | tablea                       | table             | me
public  | partitionedtable1            | partitioned table | me
public  | tableb                       | table             | me
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Version 1

I can't test this right now, but this ought to give you only top-level tables that are partitioned

```
select relname
  from pg_class
 where oid in (select partrelid from pg_partitioned_table);
```

You should be able to refine/expand that to get more details.

### Version 2

Here's a *comically verbose* solution:

```
with 
partition_parents as (
    select relnamespace::regnamespace::text as schema_name,
           relname as table_name,
           'partition_parent' as info,
           *
      from pg_class
     where relkind = 'p'), -- The parent table is relkind 'p', the partitions are regular tables, relkind 'r'

unpartitioned_tables as (     
    select relnamespace::regnamespace::text as schema_name,
           relname as table_name,
           'unpartitioned_table' as info,
           *
      from pg_class
     where relkind = 'r'
           and not relispartition
     ) -- Regular table

select * from partition_parents where schema_name not in ('information_schema','pg_catalog','api','extensions') -- Whatever you've got for schemas
union
select * from unpartitioned_tables where schema_name not in ('information_schema','pg_catalog','api','extensions') -- Whatever you've got for schemas
order by 1,2,3
```

You should be able to cut the size of that way down to match what you really want. Someone here who really gets the system catalogs should likely be able to provide a more concise version. In the plus column, it's kind of nice to add in the "partition_parent" versus "unpartitioned_table" detail, as above.

Comment: this almost gets me there, but it doesn't include the non partitioned tables

Comment: I bashed out another version that gets you unpartitioned tables, and the parents of partitioned tables.

Comment: awesome!  that's great.  I'm kind of surprised this is so hard to get.  It seems like something that should be relatively common, but I guess not.    It's too bad there isn't a simple shortcut for this like \d+ but oh well.

Answer (score 8):

Query to get all ordinary tables, including root partitioned  tables, but excluding all non-root partitioned tables:

```sql
SELECT n.nspname AS "Schema"
     , c.relname AS "Name"
     , CASE c.relkind
         WHEN 'p' THEN 'partitioned table'
         WHEN 'r' THEN 'ordinary table'
         -- more types?
         ELSE 'unknown table type'
       END AS "Type"
     , pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) AS "Owner"
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE  c.relkind = ANY ('{p,r,""}')  -- add more types?
AND    NOT c.relispartition          -- exclude child partitions
AND    n.nspname !~ ALL ('{^pg_,^information_schema$}') -- exclude system schemas
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

[The manual about `relispartition`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html)

> ... True if table or index is a partition

[`pg_get_userbyid()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) is instrumental to get the name of the owning role.

There are more types of "tables" in Postgres 12. [The manual about `relkind`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html)

> `r` = ordinary table, `i` = index, `S` = sequence, `t` = TOAST table,
> `v` = view, `m` = materialized view, `c` = composite type, `f` =
> foreign table, `p` = partitioned table, `I` = partitioned index

---

Postgres 12 also added the meta-command **`\dP`** to **psql**:

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

> `\dP[itn+] [` ***`pattern`*** `]`
>
> Lists partitioned relations. If pattern is specified, only entries whose name matches the pattern are listed. The modifiers `t` (tables) and `i` (indexes) can be appended to the command, filtering the kind of relations to list. By default, partitioned tables and indexes are listed.
>
> If the modifier `n` (“nested”) is used, or a pattern is specified, then non-root partitioned relations are included, and a column is shown displaying the parent of each partitioned relation.

So `\dPt` gets all root partitioned tables - but not ordinary tables.

Comment: that doesn't quite seem to be what I'm asking for.  It seems to give me all of the relations of partitioned tables, for example Indexes, but not what I'm looking for.  I just want the table names.  It also doesn't show the non partitioned tables.

Comment: True, not exactly what you are asking for. You can narrow down to tables, but that only includes partitioned tables. You can query the system catalogs, but I am out of time ATM ...

Comment: @Jonjilla: I added a proper query.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use a `\d*` shortcut, this query should work (though you'll need to filter out schemas not in your `search_path`):

```sql
SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relkind IN ('r','p') AND NOT relispartition;
```

Comment: this is almost right, but includes system tables like pg_statistic.  I suppose I can remove them manually, but it sure seems like there should be a simple command to get this

Answer (score -1):

--do some test in greenplum 6.14
--to find normal table ,partition table

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        t1.schemaname,
        t1.tablename,
        t1.tableowner,
    CASE
            
            WHEN t3.tablename IS NULL 
            AND t2.tablename IS NULL THEN
                'r' 
                WHEN t3.tablename IS NOT NULL 
                AND t2.tablename IS NULL THEN
                    'p-root' ELSE'p-child' 
                    END AS tabletype,
                t4.actionname,
                t4.statime 
            FROM
                pg_tables t1
                LEFT JOIN pg_partitions t2 ON t1.tablename = t2.partitiontablename 
                AND t1.schemaname = t2.partitionschemaname
                LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT schemaname, tablename FROM pg_partitions WHERE schemaname IN ( 'public', 'ods', 'tmp' ) ) t3 ON t1.tablename = t3.tablename 
                AND t1.schemaname = t3.schemaname
                LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    * 
                FROM
                    (
                    SELECT
                        schemaname,
                        objname,
                        actionname,
                        statime,
                        ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY schemaname, objname ORDER BY statime DESC ) AS rn 
                    FROM
                        pg_catalog.pg_stat_operations 
                    WHERE
                        classname = 'pg_class' 
                        AND schemaname IN ( 'public', 'ods', 'tmp' ) 
                        AND actionname IN ( 'CREATE', 'ALTER' ) 
                    ) n 
                WHERE
                    n.rn = 1 
                ) t4 ON t1.schemaname = t4.schemaname 
                AND t1.tablename = t4.objname 
            WHERE
                t1.schemaname IN ( 'public', 'ods', 'tmp' ) 
            ) o 
        WHERE
            tabletype IN ( 'r', 'p-root' ) 
        ORDER BY
            1,
            2,
        3,
    4
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.